# How can I compare two DateTime fields in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, datetime, compare

You can read the question in the title. Let's say Table A have a datetime field with "2015-12-01 00:00:00" and Table B "2014-12-01 00:00:00".

I want the data row from that table which has the bigger datetime.

Something like "datetime(A.datetime) > datetime(B.datetime)" isn't working.

Help me.

Comment: **"isn't working"** may be true, but it doesn't describe the behavior you observe. One possible result we'd expect from a statement using the expression shown in your question is MySQL Error 1064, due to the reference to a function named `DATETIME()` which does not exist in MySQL. Inequality comparisons between two `DATE`, `DATETIME` and `TIMESTAMP` expressions can be performed using the normal inequality comparison operators.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When comparing two datetimes they will be interpreted as timestamps, so just doing `A.datetime > B.datetime` should work just fine.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to compare the datetime fields as is, `A.datetime > B.datetime`.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot always do a direct comparison using <, >, <=, >= as the answer suggests. See the MySQL docs https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/using-date.html:

> When you compare a DATE, TIME, DATETIME, or TIMESTAMP to a constant
>   string with the <, <=, =, >=, >, or BETWEEN operators, MySQL normally
>   converts the string to an internal long integer for faster comparison
>   (and also for a bit more “relaxed” string checking). However, this
>   conversion is subject to the following exceptions:
>
> - When you compare two columns